# Multiple Site Authentication with Cookie

Tags: asp.net-mvc, authentication, owin, mixed-authentication

I've multiple intranet sites which are in same domain like:

- testsite/site1
- testsite/site2

In these applications I'm using [OWIN-Mixed](https://github.com/MohammadYounes/OWIN-MixedAuth) authentication. But I couldn't find the way to authenticate a user in one site and use the authentication in the others.

Is there a guide to follow it?

Answer (score 0):

OWIN-Mixed has a Windows Authentication entry point but is using regular forms authentication afterwards.

You need to allow testsite/site1 and testsite/site2 to read the same authentication cookie. To do that you need to ensure the cookie is encrypted with the same key.

You can achieve this by having the same [machineKey](https://msdn.microsoft.com/library/w8h3skw9(v=vs.100).aspx) element in both web.configs

For example, add the following to both Site1's and Site2's web.config file

```
<machineKey 
  validationKey="55304E97702846DD86E818E6A4924952B3B2D28A06E3F6CC05919C044FDEF6FC0F578FA366ECD838F34AE1806219B4AB1241FFF9CF1B935B46E559286F17AD19"
  decryptionKey="2D18B05A7B82E04AFA36D94658A64281247D81494C95C87A1F2BCDA6C1539437"
  validation="SHA1" decryption="AES"

/>
```

Make sure the cookie domain and name are the same. Also make sure both applications are on the same domain.

```
        app.UseCookieAuthentication(new CookieAuthenticationOptions
        {
            AuthenticationType = DefaultAuthenticationTypes.ApplicationCookie,
            LoginPath = new PathString("/Account/Login"),
            CookieDomain = ".testsite.com",
            CookieName = "AuthenticationCookie",

        });
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: Sorry not to mention that. In both app, machineKey ise exactly same.

Comment: Is the cookie name the same in both applications? Is the cookie writing to the same domain?

Comment: Cookie name and domain are same in both app.